# content-type not being set properly

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I am working on implementing the gRPC generated code for the flatbuffers library, and I've noticed that the python gRPC library doesn't use the user set `content-type`. According to the documentation the user can [set whatever type they want](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.35.0/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md) in the `Content-Type → "content-type" "application/grpc" [("+proto" / "+json" / {custom})]` section. I've been trying to add simply send a `+flatbuffers` which breaks the go server and the python client (trying to make sure that all the languages can work well without any issues between them).

example:
Go lang to Go lang

```
:method POST
:scheme http
:path /models.Greeter/SayHello
:authority localhost:3000
content-type application/grpc+flatbuffers
user-agent grpc-go/1.35.0
te trailers
grpc-timeout 9997779u
```

As you can see if its being called from go lang it doesn't have issues however when I call the server from the python client it clearly doesn't append the `+flatbuffers` suffix

python to Go lang

```
:scheme http
:method POST
:authority localhost:3000
:path /models.Greeter/SayHello
te trailers
content-type application/grpc
user-agent grpc-python/1.35.0 grpc-c/14.0.0 (osx; chttp2)
```

steps taken:
1- I've tried adding options to the channel:

```
with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:' + args.port, options=[('content-type', 'application/grpc+flatbuffers')]) as channel:
```

2- I've tried adding it on to the `with_call` according to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.35.0/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py

```
with_call(hello_request, metadata=[('content-type', 'application/grpc+flatbuffers')], compression=None)
```

however both options fail.

am I missing something here?

Comment: This sounds like a legitimate bug. I've created a GitHub issue for it on your behalf: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25478